# thread does not work, it's freezing my application

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a function with several loopings and database query, I want to call it asynchronously by passing a progress bar to show the user the progress.

When I call the thread the program hangs I can not even close

when I call synchContext.Post (state => etlBusiness.LoadData (progressBar), null); it freezes, it is not feasible to bring the logic of loadData to UI there are many methods being called the inside

```
 public partial class Home : Form
{
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        synchronizationContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    private SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext;

    public SynchronizationContext context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    public Thread _myThread = null;
    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _myThread = new Thread(() => LoadData(synchronizationContext, progressBar1));

        _myThread.Start();

    }

    private void LoadData(System.Threading.SynchronizationContext synchContext, ProgressBar progressBar)
    {
        string filePath = tbPath.Text;
        ETLBusiness etlBusiness = new ETLBusiness(filePath);

        synchContext.Post(state => etlBusiness.LoadData(progressBar), null);
        _myThread.Abort();
    }

}
```

Comment: *Never* call `Thread.Abort()`! You don't need it. The thread ends when its entry method returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `Thread.Abort()`, `SynchronizationContext` or even use "asynchronous" code (I assume you're referring to `await`/`async` which you cannot call unless your target API actually provides true async functionality, note that using `Task.Run` is not the same thing): WinForms has built-in functionality for running code in the UI thread in the `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` methods.

For progress reporting, I don't recommend passing-around a `ProgressBar` as that's a brittle design and means your inner business logic has a dependency on WinForms which prevents you from using it in a WPF, ASP.NET or headless process; instead you could have a private method that updates the UI via a callback, like so:

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;

public Home()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnSend_Click( Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    Task.Run( (Action)this.LoadData )
}

private void UpdateProgress( Float progress )
{
    if( this.InvokeRequired )
    {
        this.BeginInvoke( (Action<Float>)this.UpdateProgress, progress );
        return;
    }

    this.progressBar.Value = progress * this.progressBar.Maximum;
}

private void LoadData()
{
    ETLBusiness etlBusiness = new ETLBusiness(filePath);
    etlBusiness.LoadData( this.UpdateProgress ); // You'll need to replace its progressBar parameter with a callback to `this.UpdateProgress`.
}
```

Where your `ETLBusiness.LoadData` method should be changed to this:

```
void LoadData( Action<Float> progressCallback );
```

Answer (score -1):

me again.  I posted a comment in your last post.  The problem is coming from my solution.  What is happening is you are creating and starting a thread, you then, with synchContext.Post() send the logic of ETLBusiness.LoadData() back to the main thread.  What needs to happen is one of the two following options:

1. Move the logic of ETLBusiness.LoadData() into Form.LoadData() (the method called by the thread), and then use synchContext.Post(state => progressBar1.SetPercent()) to update the progressBar specifically.
2. Move the thread to the ETLBusiness class. and use synchContext.Post(state => progressBar1.SetPercent()) to update the progressBar specifically.

Sorry again, this problem came from my solution to your previous post